# link redundancy

Tags: routing, router, redundancy, vrrp

In a scenario, there are three devices R_A, R_B, R_C and connected as shown in diagram, [image: topology]

How can implement that Link 1 and Link 2 work in active and standby mode i.e. Link 2 will be active if Link 1 get fail other Link 2 on standby where Link 3 active all time with use of  auto cost single IGP process  and vrrp at all devices.

Comment: How does a layer-3 link relate to VRRP, which is a protocol for fooling devices connected at layer-2? Equal cost links will be load balanced. You may be able to do something with AD to keep the routes on one link at a higher AD than on the other.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this using ospf between R_A and R_B and give the link 1 lower metric

Comment: I'm using Auto cost//metric

Comment: So you do not want to change that?

Comment: Yes ....please suggest other way

Comment: Did your router support sla routing?

Comment: It is huawei device

Comment: it supports only NQA (Network Quality Assurance) routing Equivalent to SLA